# Singleton Pattern init call one time

Tags: swift

I need to use a singleton pattern for save a data and use this data for all my app view.

In my singleton pattern, I want to save a data from alamofire call. 
I want just call one time alamofire and after saver this data in the singleton pattern.

I've tried to call alamofire in the private init function but when I call the object of singleton pattern alamofire is call also.

How I can this please ?

```
class AccountManager {
static let sharedInstance = AccountManager()
var data = JSON()

private init() {
    Helper().alomofireGet(URL: "https://wat-stg.stardust-hosting.com/dashboard/home") { home in
        self.data = home
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You should add the code you’ve tried so far

Comment: How is your singleton implemented? A code example would be good.

Comment: I have edited my post

Comment: It's unclear what you want different from the code you posted. The `init` will only be called once and Alamofire will only be called once. Isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

```
    class AccountManager {    
        static let sharedInstance = AccountManager()
        var data = JSON()

        private init() {
            Helper().alomofireGet(URL: "https://wat-stg.stardust-hosting.com/dashboard/home") { home in
                self.data = home
            }
        }
    }
```

Your code should work but the response is coming async of your thread and at a later time than when you are calling init.

Therefore if you use something like:

```
AccountManager.sharedInstance // it will call init here
print(AccountManager.sharedInstance.data) // most probably if the init was just called a few moments ago, the  data is not yet received from the server.
```

To further understand this behaviour:

- mark the events with some prints

---

```
private init() {
        print("called init")
        Helper().alomofireGet(URL: "https://wat-stg.stardust-hosting.com/dashboard/home") { home in
            print("received data")
            self.data = home
        }
    }
```

---

- or just use some breakpoints

Comment: I use a dispatch group with dispatch notify ?

Comment: There are several ways to communicate between objects in swift. Common ones:
delegation, notification, callbaks.
Check you this article:

https://medium.com/@gavin9/3-methods-for-communicating-between-classes-in-swift-4-using-the-model-view-controller-3673f14c70b2

Comment: It seems that you need a simple way to inform another object when this result comes. Dispatch group is something that you may use for another situation. (something along the lines of waiting for multiple async operations to finish before syncing another)

Comment: Was this helpful?